# hyperledger first-network sample BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

I am following this link [first-network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html) to run hyperledger samples name `first-network`.

I am using **Ubuntu 18.04LTS**

`./byfn.sh -m generate` got successfully executed.

When I am trying to execute `./byfn.sh -m up`

I am getting **error**

`2018-05-08 10:41:55.901 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining`